# How to override quartz's property value

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, quartz-scheduler

I have spring boot application with it's application.properties file. The project has a dependency on third-party library, in my case its:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
    <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

The library has its **quartz.properties** file with configs. I would like to override some values, e.g.:

```
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount:10
```

to have another number of threads.

How can I do it using my own properties file and/or environment variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Spring boot 2 application ( assuming you have the spring-boot-starter-quartz ), you can just specify the properties directly:

spring:
  quartz:
    properties:
      org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount:10

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-quartz.html

> Quartz Scheduler configuration can be customized by using Quartz configuration properties ()spring.quartz.properties.*) and SchedulerFactoryBeanCustomizer beans, which allow programmatic SchedulerFactoryBean customization.

Answer (score 1):

You can  override this value creating your own property resolver:

```
@Bean
public Properties quartzProperties() throws IOException {
    PropertiesFactoryBean propertiesFactoryBean = new PropertiesFactoryBean();
    propertiesFactoryBean.setLocation(new ClassPathResource("/quartz.properties"));
    propertiesFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
    return propertiesFactoryBean.getObject();
}
```

And in your quartz.properties:

```
#============================================================================
# Configure Main Scheduler Properties
#============================================================================

org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId = AUTO
org.quartz.scheduler.threadsInheritContextClassLoaderOfInitializer = true
org.quartz.scheduler.skipUpdateCheck = true

#============================================================================
# Configure ThreadPool
#============================================================================

org.quartz.threadPool.class = org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount: 20
#Thread.MAX_PRIORITY 10
org.quartz.threadPool.threadPriority: 5

#============================================================================
# Configure JobStore
#============================================================================

org.quartz.jobStore.class = org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore
```

Here you can check code example.

https://www.quickprogrammingtips.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-quartz-scheduler-integration.html

https://gist.github.com/cardosomarcos/149f915b966f7bb132f436dae5af1521