# Can't configure quartz threads with spring's SchedulerFactoryBean

Tags: java, spring, quartz-scheduler

Here is my configuration for `SchedulerFactoryBean`

```
    <bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
        <property name="jobDetails">
            <list>
                <ref bean="synchronizeJobDetail"/>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="triggers">
            <list>
                <ref bean="synchronizeCronJob"/>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="quartzProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="#{T(org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean).PROP_THREAD_COUNT}">2</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

But I still can see 10(default value) of running threads

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether [SPEL](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-expression-language) can be used on a property's key; I would instead have expected a SPEL expression on its value:

application.properties:

```
quartz.threadcount=2
```

Your xml config:

```xml
<property name="quartzProperties">
  <props>
    <prop key="org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount">${quartz.threadcount}</prop>
  </props>
</property>
```

Furthermore, you can also provide a quartz [properties file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51984244/how-to-override-quartzs-property-value) in which the properties are defined. Or if you are using Spring boot, Quartz can be configured using [spring.quartz.*](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-quartz.html#boot-features-quartz) properties.

Comment: I've debugged it and it has same effect so it's totally not a problem with SPEL